# Bottom overflow by 234 Pixels

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrap my column with a SingleChildScrollView so my column content can be scrollable, however it show me the error `Bottom overflow by 234 Pixels`

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        height: height,
        width: width,
        child: Scaffold(
              body: Container(
```

How can I set a height that can be expand with the height on my container content, so the error `Bottom overflowed ...` is not show up?

Answer (score 1):

You're setting a fixed height (Media Query giving screen height)

```
 child: Container(
        height: height, // screen height
```

If the scaffold's height gets bigger than screen height, it will overflow and this is what happening here. What you want is that if the height is bigger than screen, it should be scrollable. You need to remove `height: height` from above Container. Also you can remove the the Container, it is not necessary here.

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Scaffold(
         body: Container(
```

or if `body` need to be scrollable

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
         body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
```

Find more about [scrolling widgets in flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/widgets/scrolling).